# ActiveAdmin conditionally displaying columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Any thoughts on how to conditionally display columns with the ActiveAdmin DSL?

```
index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :name
    column :address, if: current_user.admin?
    column :phone
    column :role
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
  end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :name
    if current_user.admin?
      column :address
    end
    column :phone
    column :role
    column :created_at
    column :updated_at
    actions
 end
```